# ModuleNotFoundError in importing matplotlib or seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I was trying to perform EDA in Iris Dataset on Jupyter Notebook and I was trying to import these libraries but I keep running into this error. Please help.
I have tried `pip install --upgrade pip` in my Anaconda command prompt and it responds to me with

> Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\aarushi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (21.2.4)

I also tried `pip install Pillow` but it responded with

> Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\aarushi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (8.3.1)

Also tried `pip install --upgrade pip` and the response-

> Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\aarushi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (21.2.4)

I also installed IntelliJ, Visual Studio, Weka on my system.
Here is my code-

```
import os
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-1-efa48e6030a2> in <module>
>       3 import os
>       4 import matplotlib
> ----> 5 import seaborn as sns
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py in <module>
>       1 # Import seaborn objects
> ----> 2 from .rcmod import *  # noqa: F401,F403
>       3 from .utils import *  # noqa: F401,F403
>       4 from .palettes import *  # noqa: F401,F403
>       5 from .relational import *  # noqa: F401,F403
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py in <module>
>       5 import matplotlib as mpl
>       6 from cycler import cycler
> ----> 7 from . import palettes
>       8 
>       9 
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py in <module>
>       7 from .external import husl
>       8 
> ----> 9 from .utils import desaturate, get_color_cycle
>      10 from .colors import xkcd_rgb, crayons
>      11 
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py in <module>
>      12 import matplotlib as mpl
>      13 import matplotlib.colors as mplcol
> ---> 14 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>      15 from matplotlib.cbook import normalize_kwargs
>      16 
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>
>      34 from cycler import cycler
>      35 import matplotlib
> ---> 36 import matplotlib.colorbar
>      37 import matplotlib.image
>      38 from matplotlib import rcsetup, style
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py in <module>
>      42 import matplotlib.collections as collections
>      43 import matplotlib.colors as colors
> ---> 44 import matplotlib.contour as contour
>      45 import matplotlib.cm as cm
>      46 import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py in <module>
>      15 import matplotlib.collections as mcoll
>      16 import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
> ---> 17 import matplotlib.text as text
>      18 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
>      19 import matplotlib.mathtext as mathtext
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py in <module>
>      14 from .font_manager import FontProperties
>      15 from .patches import FancyArrowPatch, FancyBboxPatch, Rectangle
> ---> 16 from .textpath import TextPath  # Unused, but imported by others.
>      17 from .transforms import (
>      18     Affine2D, Bbox, BboxBase, BboxTransformTo, IdentityTransform, Transform)
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py in <module>
>       9 from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties, get_font
>      10 from matplotlib.ft2font import LOAD_NO_HINTING, LOAD_TARGET_LIGHT
> ---> 11 from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
>      12 from matplotlib.path import Path
>      13 from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py in <module>
>      25 
>      26 import numpy as np
> ---> 27 from PIL import Image
>      28 from pyparsing import (
>      29     Combine, Empty, FollowedBy, Forward, Group, Literal, oneOf, OneOrMore,
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
> ```

Comment: Typically if you are in an anaconda environment it is preferable to do `conda install` rather than `pip install`.  You have likely managed to get your installs crossed.

Comment: Are you starting your Jupyter notebook from the environment into which you installed all these packages?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by uninstalling Anaconda and installing it again. I faced this problem initially because I had downloaded multiple environments. I suggest to properly uninstall Anaconda by searching on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also got this error.
Did you install the seaborn after jupyter notebook opened?
You should restart the kernel from the top menu Kernel > Restart kernel.